# Axis Position and Plot Color

Tags: ios, colors, position, core-plot

I have got two problems.

1. My axis are not meeting on proper point i.e. I want 0 of my y-axis to intersect first value of x-axis. I have tried many ways through `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` property, but I am unable to manage it.
2. Secondly, my 2nd plot on right hand side is not plotting of red color as I have coded. Can you tell me what possibly may I be missing?

Figure:

[image]

Code snippets of I have written:

```js
NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;

// Setup plot spaces

//1- calorie
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0f;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay * 7.0f)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(600)];

//2- exercise
plotSpace2 = [[[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init] autorelease];
plotSpace2.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace2.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
plotSpace2.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                 length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(60.0)];
[graph addPlotSpace:plotSpace2];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.graphHost.hostedGraph.axisSet;

// Axes
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
NSTimeInterval oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;    
x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;

 CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.majorIntervalLength   = CPTDecimalFromInt(200);
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 9;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0);
y.title = @"Calories Burned";

CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[[CPTXYAxis alloc] init]retain];
y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
y2.majorIntervalLength  = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5.0");
y2.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;
y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"-20.0");
y2.title = @"Exercise Time (min)";

//I added these lines too
//adding 2nd axis
NSMutableArray *newAxes = [graph.axisSet.axes mutableCopy];
[newAxes addObject:y2];
graph.axisSet.axes = newAxes;
[newAxes release];

 CPTScatterPlot *caloriePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
caloriePlot.dataSource = self;
caloriePlot.identifier = @"Calorie";

//create styles and symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *calorieLineStyle = [caloriePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
calorieLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
calorieLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor greenColor];
caloriePlot.dataLineStyle  = calorieLineStyle;

[graph addPlot:caloriePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

CPTScatterPlot *exercisePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
exercisePlot.dataSource = self;
exercisePlot.identifier = @"Exercise";

CPTMutableLineStyle *exerciseLineStyle = [exercisePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
exerciseLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
exerciseLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor redColor];
exerciseLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f], nil];   
exercisePlot.dataLineStyle  =calorieLineStyle;
[graph addPlot:exercisePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace2];
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hard to tell without seeing more of your code. How many plot spaces do you have? Which plot space is each axis assigned to? What are the plot ranges of each plot space?
2. Change this line:

   ```
   exercisePlot.dataLineStyle = calorieLineStyle;
   ```

   to

   ```
   exercisePlot.dataLineStyle = exerciseLineStyle;
   ```

Comment: Thankyou @Eric Skroch. My 2nd problem is solved. I just blindly copied the code for second plot. I have edited my starting code for more details.

Comment: Can you please consider another problem related to this...? I have added four lines after `y2` axis to add y2 to axis set. These lines are crashing my program when I am trying to configure my axis in bar plot just by using code above. I need to have multiple y axis for bar plot too just like in figure.

Comment: Are you setting any axis constraints? If so, the constraints will override the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal`.

Comment: Yes. I want my axis to float, so that's why I have used `[CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:]`. So what should I do now?

Comment: Set the padding on the plot area frame to move the axes away from the edge of the graph. Use the constraints to hold them in place when the graph scrolls. Look at the Real Time Plot in the Plot Gallery example app to see how it's done.